# How can I say this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tryng to say onClick of the link with class "myLink" show the div with the class "myDiv". And on focusOut hide the "myDiv" div. But my problem is with the focusOut part. Right now my code looks like this:

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<a href="#" class="myLink">Click Me</a>

$('.myDiv').hide();
$('.myLink').click(function(event) {
    $('.myDiv').show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
$('.myLink').focusout(function(event) {
    $('.myDiv').hide();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

problem is, if the user clicks anywhere other than the "myLink" link it is considered focusOut. I don't want the div to hide if the user clicks within the div, I want it only to hide if the user clicks anywhere other than the link **AND** the div. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried binding to the div's focusout instead of the link's focusout?